# Difference between for and of

Tags: prepositions

Is it 
1. The renewal dates of the books
2. The renewal dates for the books

Comment: EHello, Ghj. Either may be used, as [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=renewal+dates+for%2Crenewal+dates+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crenewal%20dates%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crenewal%20dates%20of%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest. The 'for' variant emphasises the borrower's responsibility more. But the single-link answer makes this general reference.

Answer (score 1):

> The renewal date of the books.

suggests that the date is something the books *have*.

> The renewal date for the books.

suggests that the date is something the books *receive*.

Thus once you have picked the books up from the library, they have a renewal date, and you would speak of it as "the renewal date of the books". However, should you want to borrow them a little longer you may renew the books, thus receiving "a new renewal date for the books".